# Erlang: Are there any Atompub (Atom Publishing Protocol) libraries available?

Tags: erlang, atompub

Are there any [Atompub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)) (Atom Publishing Protocol) libraries available for Erlang?

Comment: question from someone who never used atom: what should an atom library do that an xml library in itself cannot?

Comment: Things like handling the CRUD operations properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are almost no RSS or Atom libraries for erlang. I contemplated writing some once but wasn't sufficiently motivated so I never did. For some reason erlang developers haven't felt the need to write one yet.

Comment: Probably because so far no app written in erlang has needed it.

Comment: That's certainly the reason for my lack of motivation anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly ... there are server libraries :

- wrote a while back an [atompub-pubsub bridge for ejabberd](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/atom_pubsub/trunk/src/atom_pubsub.erl).
  In use [here](http://www.buddymob.com/), it validates Tim Bray's APE.
- and an [atom entry validation code](http://github.com/cstar/atom-validation-for-ejabberd-xml) (still for ejabberd's XML format)

As for client libraries, unless I need full coverage, an *adhoc* ibrowse/xmerl_xpath combo should do the trick.